# retrieving entire row for user logging in - mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some code I have written with php. I have written some code so that when a user logs in successfully their username is saved in a session then I can echo the $_SESSION['user_name']. I was wondering if someone could help me out with some lines of code so that when a user logs in I can also retrieve the user_id or user_email for only that user and be able to echo it to another page.

Here is what I have so far but it isn't echoing what I want.

```
  $this->db_connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '1', 'test');


         // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
           if ($this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
         echo "Connection Failed " . $this->db_connection->connect_errno . "";
         }



         // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
         if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

             // escape the POST stuff
             $this->user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
             $this->user_password = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_password']);


             // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
             $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_password, user_email
                     FROM members
                     WHERE user_name = '{$this->user_name}' AND user_password = '{$this->user_password}'";
             $query = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
            $result = $query->fetch_object();



            // if the username exists and if the password is a correct match
             if (($query->num_rows == 1) && ($this->user_password === $result->user_password)) {

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo $row['user_email'];
    }
          $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result->user_name;
          $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;

          $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;


          setcookie("_time", "cookie_value", time() + 3600);


        //redirect to this page if the user has logged in successfully
        header("Location: testing.php");


                 } 
            }
```

I have tried placing the while loop in different sections of the function but still not working

Comment: have start session on to top of each page `session_start();`

Comment: I have session start in the __construct function of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $result->user_name;
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $result->user_email;
```

or simply

```
$_SESSION = $result
```

if you've done `fetch_assoc` instad of `fetch_object`

I recommend you to take a auth key and store it in session, better than doing user_logged in, which is highly insecure.

```
/**
 * Returns an encrypted & utf8-encoded
 */
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

/**
 * Returns decrypted original string
 */
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

this is for the encryption and decryption.
When user logs in, modify sql and add a random value to the encrypt. Store it also on the session. When checking if logged, select the key from the db with the username, and compare it with the current session key.

```
if ($result->key != $_SESSION["auth_key"]) {
// do whatever
}
```

Comment: I added $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result->user_email;
and now it works fine thanks. How can I create an auth key? Could you post a link about auth keys and how to use them?

Comment: @user3671179 yes,  It'll take me 2 minutes. I tell you when I have it